# Getting an unexpected trace for getpixel32. Can anybody see why?

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmapdata

When running the following code, "-2" is being traced and I am wrecking my head trying to understand why.

```
var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(1,1,true,0xFFFFFFFF);
bmd.setPixel32(0,0, 0x32FF6B45);
trace(0x32FF6B45-bmd.getPixel32(0,0));
```

As far as I can tell, it should trace 0. 0x32FF6B45 is initially assigned to the pixel at coords 0,0. That value should be returned in bmd.getPixel32(0,0) and then, when it's subtracted from 0x32FF6B45, it should result in 0. Why the heck am I getting -2?

EDIT:

I've traced out the values individually and it makes sense that the operation in the trace above results in -2 because tracing out 0x32FF6B45 results in 855599941 and tracing out bmd.getPixel32(0,0) results in 855599943. The question now is why the heck are those values different? Whey doesn't bmd.getPixel32(0,0) also trace out 855599941?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, and I believe it is related to premultiplied alpha, as [described here](http://www.quasimondo.com/archives/000665.php).  In my code I was setting a pixel to 0xa08800ff and getting back 0xa08700ff.  If you need alphas other than 0xff, then unfortunately it may be necessary to simultaneously store all your pixel values in a separate data structure too.

Answer (score -1):

That is expected.

> getPixel

This will return a value: #RRGGBB (rgb / red, green, blue)

> getPixel32

This will return a value: #AARRGGBB (argb / alpha, red, green, blue)

Example:

```
trace('test 0x32FF6B45: '+0x32FF6B45);
var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(1,1,true,0xFFFFFFFF);
trace('setting 0,0 to 0x32FF6B45');
bmd.setPixel32(0,0, 0x32FF6B45);
var color:* = bmd.getPixel32(0,0)
trace('0,0: '+color);
trace(color-bmd.getPixel32(0,0));
```

Results:

```
test 0x32FF6B45: 855599941
setting 0,0 to 0x32FF6B45
0,0: 855599943
0
```

From what I can tell, you're using a color that is out-of-bounds to Flash.  I'm not sure of the color range, but I know in previous experiences when taking photoshop elements with many colors, sometimes objects failed to import because the color value was out of bounds.

@Jari is also correct about the transparency.